# Source of Fedora Core 6 Live CD

Tags: fedora, livecd, download

I have spent quite a bit of time trying to search for a source for the above.

There are many webpages pointing to (what I believe is) the original link - http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/fedora/projects/live/FC-6-i386-livecd-1.iso

However, using this with the below hopeful's was unfruitful (*Added to*):

[*The Internet Archive - Software Collection*](http://archive.org/details/fedora-6_release)
[The internet Archive - Way Back Machine (All crawled dates)](http://web.archive.org/web/20110710141631/http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/fedora/projects/live/FC-6-i386-livecd-1.iso)
[Google's cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=cache%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fdownload.fedora.redhat.com%2Fpub%2Ffedora%2Fprojects%2Flive%2FFC-6-i386-livecd-1.iso&oq=cache%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fdownload.fedora.redhat.com%2Fpub%2Ffedora%2Fprojects%2Flive%2FFC-6-i386-livecd-1.iso&gs_l=hp.12...710.45199.0.45977.7.7.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....2...1c.1.26.psy-ab..7.0.0.DG5TSTOZPrM&pbx=1)
http://www.oldversion.com/linux/

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**EDIT:**

Also, as [goldilocks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/25985) reminded me due to [this comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90485/source-of-fedora-core-6-live-cd?noredirect=1#comment136004_90485), I should have pointed out - Have found the archives at http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/publiclist/Fedora/6/i386/ and (not like they should be very different) looked through all of them.

Comment: http://archive.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/core/6/i386/iso/

Comment: Is this the *live CD* or the installer DVD? I believe they are different, and if so, I need as close an installed environment running off CD/USB, as possible, hence believe I need the live CD, no? P.S Thanks for the typo correction - Was very late at night when I was typing this up :)

Comment: Yeah, they probably are different.  According to this: http://news.softpedia.com/news/First-Fedora-Live-CD-34126.shtml that was the first year fedora had a live image, so one did exist...

Comment: True. Think I found this info on the same site. So why provide archives of everything but (PPC, x64, x86, RescueCD, etc....) ... Grrr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through another Q&A site, the ISO was found, and is now up at http://archive.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/projects/live/FC-6-i386-livecd-1.iso